# Equation using modular inverse

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

In the search for the private key of a Merkle–Hellman knapsack cryptosystem. I have encountered the following relationship:
$$b=a^{-1}\pmod m$$
I have found $b=2017$ and $m=65535$ and the modular inverse equation can be written as:
$$2017=a^{-1}\pmod {65535}$$
I want to find $a$, but came only with a brute force solution and I have troubles understanding this type of equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://extended%20euclidean%20algorithm) to find integers $a$ and $b$ such that
$$
2017a + 65535b = 1 .
$$

Then $2017$ is the inverse of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

$$  \gcd( 65535, 2017 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 65535 }{ 2017 } = 32 +  \frac{ 991 }{ 2017 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 2017 }{ 991 } = 2 +  \frac{ 35 }{ 991 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 991 }{ 35 } = 28 +  \frac{ 11 }{ 35 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 35 }{ 11 } = 3 +  \frac{ 2 }{ 11 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 11 }{ 2 } = 5 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 2 }{ 1 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
 & & 32 & & 2 & & 28 & & 3 & & 5 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 32 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 65 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 1852 }{ 57 }   & &   \frac{ 5621 }{ 173 }   & &   \frac{ 29957 }{ 922 }   & &   \frac{ 65535 }{ 2017 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  32  \\  
  \frac{ 32 }{ 1 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 65 }{ 2 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  28  \\  
  \frac{ 1852 }{ 57 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 5621 }{ 173 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  5  \\  
  \frac{ 29957 }{ 922 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 65535 }{ 2017 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  0  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

So, you see, by the main property of continued fraction convergents, which is that the little 2 by 2 determinants of consecutive convergents are $\pm 1,$ such as $32 \cdot 2 - 65 \cdot 1 = -1,$ or $65 \cdot 57 - 1852 \cdot 2 = 1,$ at the end

$$ 65535 \cdot 922 - 2017 \cdot 29957 = 1. $$ Or,
  $$ 65535 \cdot 922 + 2017 \cdot (-29957) = 1. $$ If preferred, we can carefully adjust the 922 by -2017, adjust the -29957 by +65535, for
 $$ 65535 \cdot (-1095) + 2017 \cdot 35578 = 1. $$